# Is Magento PWA venia setup support B2B features out of the box?

Tags: magento2.4, pwa, magento2-enterprise, venia

We are using Magento 2.4.1 Enterprise Edition with B2B. Is **Magento PWA venia setup** support B2B features out of the box? or do we need to integrate separately?

Also, please provide a list of PWA that supports Magento 2 B2B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are using Magento 2.4.1 Enterprise Edition with B2B. Is Magento PWA
> venia setup support B2B features out of the box?

No as of Q4 2020 it's not yet supported. According to the public graphql project board [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/projects/27?card_filter_query=b2b) you can expect initial graphql support for B2B scenarios with Magento release 2.4.2. which would then allow PWA solutions built on graphql like venia to take advantage of this. 2.4.2 should be coming in Q1 in 2021 - not sure how soon thereafter Venia might support it.

> or do we need to integrate separately?

yes

Comment: Thanks, do you know any 3rd party PWA supports b2b? I contacted scandipwa and vuestorefront but both don't support b2b.

Comment: I am not aware of any but I haven't done any further research on this. While it may be possible for a PWA to use a REST api to get the b2b data my guess would be that most would wait until b2b graphql is available out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the updates.